# Здесь появляется ошибка, почему-то else без if и getWindow() красное (это фрагмент)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
package com.talk.talktools;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Switch;

public class fragmentsettings extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentsettings, container, false);
        return v;
    }
private Switch switch1;
    private Window window;

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        Switch switch1 = view.findViewById(R.id.switch1);

        if (switch1.isChecked());
        getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(0xFFFF8800);
        else
        getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(0x00000000);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не верно написан IF. Из фрагмента нельзя вызвать `getWindow()`. Для вызова `setNavigationBarColor()` необходим минимум API 21 (Lollipop).

```
package com.talk.talktools;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Switch;

public class fragmentsettings extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentsettings, container, false);
        return v;
    }
    private Switch switch1;
    private Window window;

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        Switch switch1 = view.findViewById(R.id.switch1);
        window = getActivity().getWindow();
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            if (switch1.isChecked()){
                window.setNavigationBarColor(0xFFFF8800);
            }else{
                window.setNavigationBarColor(0x00000000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: хорошо, а как тогда красить НавБар?

Comment: я поменял код, но не красит, андроид 6.0.1 Почему может быть такое?

Comment: Может быть цвет неверно указан. Желательно его брать из ресурсов, примерно так: `getResources().getColor(R.color.my_color)`

Answer (score 1):

Может стоит после if убрать ; ?)

Comment: помогло, спасибо, не подскажете, почему getWindow() красное?

Comment: После ; блок if закрывается =) значит else не может быть связка if() else

Comment: это я уже понял, а getWindow почему красное?

Comment: Я так понимаю getWindow после else подсвечивалось?

Comment: и после if, и после else, сейчас тоже подсвечивается

Comment: @F0x1d может вам стоит забросить программирование. Таких элементарных вещей не знать....

Comment: @Санаев зачем же сразу забрасывать предлагаете? Человек хочет понять - почему. И что, если человек чего-то не знает, сразу надо предлагать ему забрасывать программирование?

Comment: @misdeed тогда может стоит начинать изучать java а не задавать тут глупых вопросов?

Comment: @Санаев, хорошая идея! Полностью с вами согласен. Но вот лично я по себе скажу, мне проще что-либо запомнить/понять - когда я непосредственно задаю вопрос, и получаю ответ. Не всегда до меня что-то доходит, если я сам пытаюсь это понять.

Comment: @misdeed это слишком глупый вопрос. 2 или 3 урок по java. даже не по java любого си подобного языка программирования